# Почему не работает js в Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

В остальных браузерах работает а в Mozilla Firefox нет, это скрипт для сворачивания меню при опускании вниз скроллингом.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  // Top navbar animation
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $(document).bind('shrink-menu-init', function(e, status) {
    var topBarHeight = $('.navbar-extra-top').outerHeight(); // getting the height of the nabar-extra-top
    scrollMark = Math.max(topBarHeight, 30); // forced minimum of 30
    style = ".menu-shrink {top : 0px !important;}";
    if ( !$('#ShrinkMenu').length ) {
      $( "<style></style>" ).attr('id','ShrinkMenu').data('scrollMark',scrollMark).appendTo( "head" ); // add custom CSS for height offset
    }
    $('#ShrinkMenu').html(style);
  });
  // navbar adjustments on scroll
  $(document).bind('shrink-menu', function(e, status){
    scrollMark = $('#ShrinkMenu').data('scrollMark');
    // when scroll hits height of navbar top, apply style changes
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() < scrollMark ) {
      $('#MainMenu').removeClass('scrolled menu-shrink');
    } else {
      $('#MainMenu').addClass('scrolled menu-shrink');
    }
  });
  // trigger shrink-menu on scroll
  $(window).resize( function(){
    $(document).trigger('shrink-menu-init');
  });
  $(window).scroll( function(){
    $(document).trigger('shrink-menu');
  });

    // Sub-navbar affix on scroll
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if ($('#SubMenu').length) {
        $('#SubMenu').affix({
            offset: {
                top: function () {
                    return $('#SubMenu').parent().offset().top - $('#navbar-main-container').outerHeight();
                },
            }
        }).css('top',$('#navbar-main-container').outerHeight());
        // Update values on window resize
        $(window).resize( function() {
            theTop = $('#SubMenu').parent().offset().top - $('#navbar-main-container').outerHeight();
            $('#SubMenu').data('bs.affix').options.offset = { top: theTop };
        });
    }

    // accordions - always have 1 panel open
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if ( $('.panel-heading').length ) {

        $('.panel-heading').on('click',function(e){
            if($(this).parents('.panel').children('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')){
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
    }

    // Tooltips
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        placement: function(tip, trigger) {
            // show above, unless no space. show bottom on affixed sub-nav
            return ( $(trigger).parents('#SubMenu.affix').length ) ? 'bottom' : 'auto top';
        }
    });

    // owl carousel
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if ( $('.featured-carousel').length ) {
        $(".featured-carousel").owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayHoverPause: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 3800,
            autoplaySpeed: 800,
            navSpeed: 500,
            dots: false,
            nav: true,
            navText: [
                '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
                '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
            ]
        });
    }

    // Navbar Hover/Click Responsive Behavior
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  collapseSize = 1299; // 768;

  // hover sub-menu items
  $('.navbar-nav a').click( function(e) {
    $this = $(e.target);
    href = $this.attr('href'); // Link URL

    // Check link value
    if (href === undefined || !href.length || href === '#' || href === 'javascript:;') {
      href = false;
    }
    // Link behavior
    if ($this.hasClass('dropdown-toggle')) {
      // Parent menu items
      if ($(window).width() > collapseSize) {
        if (href) {
          // large screens, follow the parent menu link when clicked
          if (e.which !== 2) {
            window.location.href = href;
          }
        }
       } else if ( $this.parent().hasClass('open') && href !== false) {
        // small screens, 1st tap opens sub-menu & 2nd tap follows link
        $(document).trigger('collapse-menus');
        window.location.href = href;
      }
    } else {
      // All other menu items, close menu on click
      $(document).trigger('collapse-menus');
    }
  });
  // Keep parent menus open on sub-menu expand
  $(document).on('show.bs.dropdown', function(obj) {
    if ($(window).width() <= collapseSize) {
      $(obj.target).parents('.show-on-hover').addClass('open');
    }
  });
  $('.navbar a:not(.dropdown-toggle)').click( function(e) {

    $this = $(e.target);
    href = $this.attr('href'); // Link URL

    // Check link value
    if (href === undefined || !href.length || href === '#' || href === 'javascript:;') {
      href = false;
    }
    // Link behavior
    if ($(window).width() > collapseSize) {
      if (href) {
        // large screens, follow the parent menu link when clicked
        if (e.which !== 2) {
          window.location.href = href;
        }
      }
     } else if ( $this.parent().hasClass('open') && href !== false) {
      // small screens, 1st tap opens sub-menu & 2nd tap follows link
      $(document).trigger('collapse-menus');
      window.location.href = href;
    }
  });
  // Close all menus
  $(document).on('collapse-menus', function () {
    $('.collapse.in').removeClass('in').children().removeClass('open');
  });
  // Hover styling helpers
  $('.navbar-nav > li.show-on-hover').hover(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > collapseSize) {
      $(this).addClass('open');
    }
  }, function() {
    if ($(window).width() > collapseSize) {
      $(this).removeClass('open');
    }
  });



    // Things we want to trigger once, forcefully, after loading the page
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Fire the menu shrink function
    $(document).trigger('shrink-menu-init');
    $(document).trigger('shrink-menu');

});
```

Comment: Во-первых, Mozilla - это компания. Их браузер называется Firefox. Во-вторых, что именно значит "не работает"? Ошибки в консоли какие-нибудь появляются?

Comment: Попробуйте на новом FF